# Selenium WebDriver: how to wait until WebElement event?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, dom-events, wait

Is there the way for the `WebDriverWait` object to wait until the certain DOM event of the `WebElement`? For example, to wait until the element is clicked. This could allow to mix the elements handling by the testing script automatically and by the user manually.

Comment: Yes, you can wait until `the certain DOM event`, what is your exact requirement? Thanks

Comment: For example, how to wait until element is clicked?

Comment: You can use `click()` method to click the element. Thanks